# Error occurs when function is used to delete a dynamically created button

Tags: javascript, html

```js
Element.prototype.delete = function() {
        document.getElementById("button-section").removeChild(this);
    }    

    function createButton(id,text,eventType,event)
    {
        const button = document.createElement("button");
        button.id = String(id);
        button.innerText = String(text);
        button.classList.add("ActionButton");
        document.getElementById("button-section").appendChild(button);
        button.addEventListener(eventType,event);
    }

    createButton("testButton","click me to test","click",function()
    {
        document.getElementById("testButton").delete();
    });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id='button-section'></div>
</body>
</html>
```

I have two functions right now, one for dynamically creating a button, and the other is for deleting that button. The function used to delete the button is generating this error:

```
indexCode.js:9 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node': The node to be removed is not a child of this node.
    at HTMLButtonElement.Element.delete (indexCode.js:9:51)
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (indexCode.js:24:53)
```

js

```js
    Element.prototype.delete = function() {
        document.getElementById("button-section").removeChild(this);
    }    

    function createButton(id,text,eventType,event)
    {
        const button = document.createElement("button");
        button.id = String(id);
        button.innerText = String(text);
        button.classList.add("ActionButton");
        document.getElementById("button-section").appendChild(button);
        button.addEventListener(eventType,event);
    }

    createButton("testButton","click me to test","click",function()
    {
        document.getElementById("testButton").delete();
    });
```

html

```
<div id='button-section'>

</div>
```

Comment: I found your code is working just fine. But i would suggest you to use `element.remove` to remove that child. You can use something like this

`    createButton("testButton","click me to test","click",function()
    {
        this.remove();
    });`

Comment: Why are you adding to the element prototype? And you are recreating https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/remove ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want remove a element,you can directly call `element.remove()`,no need for `removeChild`,you can read more document [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/remove)

```js
function createButton(id,text,eventType,event)
{
    const button = document.createElement("button");
    button.id = String(id);
    button.innerText = String(text);
    button.classList.add("ActionButton");
    document.getElementById("button-section").appendChild(button);
    button.addEventListener(eventType,event);
}

createButton("testButton","click me to test","click",function()
{
    document.getElementById("testButton").remove();
});
```

```html
<div id='button-section'></div>
```